# How to condense this regex with a bunch of repeated segements?

Tags: regex

How would I condense this? I tried using brackets and /2 but that didn't seem to work. Anyone know? This is kind of ugly.

```
^(\$|)[A-Z0-9_\- ]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t[0-9\.\-]*\t
```

I'm using a Perl 6.18 compatible (I think it's .18) regex engine.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. Do you care about what `[0-9\.\-]*` matches?

Comment: actually there should only be max 1 decimal and max 1 minus because it's just a number but it's not really that important. It's just to validate some data using the whole regex, and the regex is already sufficiently complicated to only match some pretty specific csv data format. As you can see I'm pretty new at regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group and repetition quantifier.

```
^(\$|)[A-Z0-9_\- ]*\t(?:[0-9\.\-]*\t){6}
```

OR

```
^\$?[-A-Z0-9_ ]*\t(?:[0-9.-]*\t){6}
```

Comment: You can also move the `-` in the first character class to the end, eliminating the need for escaping.

Comment: yep, at the last or at the first.